# Windows Phone, erro ao salvar texto (IsolatedStorage)

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Estou tentando rodar um app (Windows Phone 8.1) que, por enquanto, somente irá salvar um texto em um arquivo txt na memória do celular e também devera ler o arquivo txt.
Ao tentar salvar o texto, o Visual Studio 2013 me retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//Objeto que dá acesso ao sistema de armazenamento da aplicação
IsolatedStorageFile armazenamento = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
//FileStream responsável por abrir o arquivo, ou criá-lo se não existir
IsolatedStorageFileStream arquivo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("doc.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, armazenamento);
//Leitor de streams que será usado para ler o conteúdo do arquivo
StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(arquivo);
//Passando para o TextBox o conteúdo do arquivo
txtTexto.Text = leitor.ReadToEnd();
//Liberando o objeto de leitura do arquivo que foi aberto
leitor.Close();
//Liberando o arquivo que foi aberto
arquivo.Close();
}


private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

//Objeto que dá acesso ao sistema de armazenamento da aplicação
IsolatedStorageFile armazenamento = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
//FileStream responsável por abrir o arquivo, ou criá-lo se não existir
IsolatedStorageFileStream arquivo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("doc.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, armazenamento);
//Objeto responsável por escrever no arquivo
StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(arquivo);
//Escrevendo no arquivo o conteúdo do TextBox
escritor.Write(txtTexto.Text);
//Liberando o objeto de leitura do arquivo que foi aberto
escritor.Close();
//Liberando o arquivo que foi aberto
arquivo.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo erro, tem a ver com permissões. Verifica se a classe **IsolatedStorageFile** não tem alguma coisa relacionada a permissões. O diretório já existe?

Para ter mais informações, debuga o código e vê se tem algo na Inner Exception.

Comment: Olá @00lenon, consegui resolver (solução como resposta). Porém, sabe me dizer se eu consigo exportar de alguma forma esse arquivo "doc.txt"? Quando digo exportar, pode ser para web, ou algum diretório na rede em que o device esteja conectado. Obrigado

Comment: Ola @ReneSá, não cara, não sei te dizer. :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema inserindo o código que "lê" o arquivo (.txt) na inicialização do app:

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        {
            //Objeto que dá acesso ao sistema de armazenamento da aplicação
            IsolatedStorageFile armazenamento = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            try
            {
                //FileStream responsável por abrir o arquivo, ou criá-lo se não existir
                IsolatedStorageFileStream arquivo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("doc.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, armazenamento);
                //Leitor de streams que será usado para ler o conteúdo do arquivo
                StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(arquivo);
                //Passando para o TextBox o conteúdo do arquivo
                txtTexto.Text = leitor.ReadToEnd();
                //Liberando o objeto de leitura do arquivo que foi aberto
                leitor.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

    }


    private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Objeto que dá acesso ao sistema de armazenamento da aplicação
        IsolatedStorageFile armazenamento = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //FileStream responsável por abrir o arquivo, ou criá-lo se não existir
        IsolatedStorageFileStream arquivo = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("doc.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, armazenamento);
        //Objeto responsável por escrever no arquivo
        StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(arquivo);
        //Escrevendo no arquivo o conteúdo do TextBox
        escritor.Write(txtTexto.Text);
        //Liberando o objeto de leitura do arquivo que foi aberto
        escritor.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Utilizo esse código para gerenciar gravação e leitura de arquivos no Store dos meus Apps**

```
    public static void SaveFileJson(string fileName, string jsonString, bool append = false)
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, !append ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append, store)))
                    {
                        sw.Write(jsonString);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

public static string OpenFileJson(string fileName)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (store.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, store))
                {
                    long length = stream.Length;
                    byte[] decoded = new byte[length];
                    stream.Read(decoded, 0, (int)length);
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded, 0, (int)length);
                }
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente este código, observe o FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read:

```
using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Notes.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, isolatedStorage)
{
//...
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371183/194717